# Member-Attribute for inetOrgPerson object in ApacheDS

Tags: java, ldap, apacheds, apache-directory

I'm using ApacheDS as LDAP server. I need some groups to manage permission on different application. For example, a group called "jira-users", which are able to login to jira. So I need an attribute where I can store the member groups of an user. I'm using the objectClass called inetOrgPerson which seems suiteable for storing users.

From Active Directory which I was working on in the past, I remember an attribute called **memberOf**. Seems that this is AD specific, since the inetOrgPerson class has an attribute called **member**. According to the documentation, it does the same: Storing groups where the user is a member of. But when I try to add this to a inetOrgPerson object, I get the following error in Apache Directory studio:

> Warning! This attribute isn't allowed according to the scheme! 
>   Would you like to still use it?

When I try this pressing *yes*, I got the following exception:

> Fehler beim Ausführen des LDIF
>    - [LDAP: error code 65 - OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for MessageType : MODIFY_REQUES   java.lang.Exception: [LDAP: error code
>   65 - OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for MessageType : MODIFY_REQUEST
>   Message ID : 262
>       Modify Request
>           Object : 'cn=Testuser,ou=user,dc=example,dc=com'
>               Modification[0]
>                   Operation :  add
>                   Modification member: cn=Testgruppe,ou=user,dc=example,dc=comorg.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.ModifyRequestImpl@868031e2:
>   ERR_277 Attribute member not declared in objectClasses of entry
>   cn=Testuser,ou=user,dc=example,dc=com]    at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkResponse(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1268)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.access$9(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1236)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$4.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:716)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1163)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1099)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.modifyEntry(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:738)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifRunnable.importLdifRecord(ImportLdifRunnable.java:515)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifRunnable.importLdif(ImportLdifRunnable.java:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ExecuteLdifRunnable.executeLdif(ExecuteLdifRunnable.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ExecuteLdifRunnable.run(ExecuteLdifRunnable.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.UpdateEntryRunnable.run(UpdateEntryRunnable.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
>
> [LDAP: error code 65 - OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for
>   MessageType : MODIFY_REQUEST Message ID : 262
>       Modify Request
>           Object : 'cn=Testuser,ou=user,dc=example,dc=com'
>               Modification[0]
>                   Operation :  add
>                   Modification member: cn=Testgruppe,ou=user,dc=example,dc=comorg.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.ModifyRequestImpl@868031e2:
>   ERR_277 Attribute member not declared in objectClasses of entry
>   cn=Testuser,ou=user,dc=example,dc=com]

I tried to add it like described here http://morenews.blogspot.de/2010/12/adding-active-directory-properties-to.html with ldapadd. This gave me no error and when i look at ou=schema,cn=other,ou=objectClasses I see my inserted values. But when I create a new inetOrgPerson, there is no possibility to use it! What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Configure the memberOf overlay**

•   sudo -i

•   slapcat -n 0 | grep olcModuleLoad

•   if modules then

1. ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///
2. dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
3. changetype: modify
4. add: olcModuleLoad
5. olcModuleLoad: memberof.la
6. Hit Enter

modifying entry "cn=module{0},cn=config" should display

•   if no modules then

1. ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -Q -H ldapi:///
2. dn: cn=module,cn=config
3. cn: module
4. objectClass: olcModuleList
5. olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap (search for memberof.la to find the correct path)
6. olcModuleLoad: memberof.la
7. Hit Enter

adding new entry "cn=module,cn=config" should display

•   hit ctrl c

•   slapcat -n 0 | grep olcModuleLoad

o   olcModuleLoad: {0}back_mdb

o   olcModuleLoad: {1}memberof.la

**Apply the memberOf overlay**

ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///

dn: olcOverlay=memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config

objectClass: olcOverlayConfig

objectClass: olcMemberOf

olcOverlay: memberof

olcMemberOfRefint: TRUE

Hit Enter

adding new entry "olcOverlay=memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config" should display

hit ctrl c

Answer (score -1):

Actually the `member` attribute type does not "store groups where a user is a member of", on the contrary it contains the distinguished names of objects that are on a list or in a group.

`inetOrgPerson` object class does not and should not hold any "member" attribute, `groupOfNames` does and even requires it since it represents a set of named objects that are stored in "member" attribute.

(see [RFC 4519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519), [RFC 2798](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798))

I guess what you want is to add **memberOf** attribute to inetOrgPerson. For that you need to define the "memberOf" attribute type and edit the inetOrgPerson object class in the schema. You must add the attribute type first because the object class refers to it.

(see also : [Adding Schema Elements in Apache DS](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/2.3.1-adding-schema-elements.html))